# Cannot run Grails from command prompt

Tags: grails, windows-7-x64

I’ve added a `GRAILS_HOME` environment variable, which points to the folder in which I extracted the Grails distribution zip, and I’ve added `%GRAILS_HOME%\bin` to my path. Yet after I open a new command prompt, the “grails” command is still not found. Does anyone have any clue as to why this is happening?

I’m running Grails 2.2 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem on Windows 7 64 bit and Grails version 2.*

By removing local neither maven repository nor installed plugins repository doesn't help.
I found - just set properties of `%GRAILS_HOME%/bin/grails.bat` and `startGrails.bat` as Run in compatibility mode: Windows XP (Service Pack 3).

To do that You need to have local PC Administrators rights.

/igors

Answer (score 0):

have you create JAVA_HOME in there?

Comment: Yes, the path variable contains both %JAVA_HOME%\bin as %GRAILS_HOME%\bin

Comment: example GRAILS_HOME c:/grails and Path c:/grails/bin

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are experiencing [[STS-2530] Problem deploying Grails App if workspace path has a space](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2530).  Jira shows the issue as resolved but it would not hurt to check that you do not have a space in your workspace path as it my trip up grails.

Comment: It does not get beyond 'grails is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

Answer (score 0):

Do the following.

1. Go to your command prompt, execute the Path command. If everything has been set right your paths should show up as complete paths starting with C:... If the paths show up with the **%** sign that means your paths need to be set correctly. I did noticed that in your example you have used the forward slash - I am assuming that is a typo, because that will be a problem.
2. Another way to trouble shoot the issue is CD to the location C:\Grails\bin, execute the command grails.bat, if it executes you are in a good place that means you have to tweak your paths - following this path might give you a clue about other issues....

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the bin folder of your grails installation. The grails.bat file could be missing. I had this problem today and solved it by downloading the zip file again.